# Recycle view scrolling issue with Holder in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created one recycle view adapter in which i am filling object of view holder on the click of the row.so that i have always latest view holder object whenever i click on the recycle view row.

**Issue** is whenever i scrolls recycle view calls bind view holder and values of my view holder changes run time without clicking of any row

I have tried so many ways to hold my current object of clicked row but i am not getting that`enter code here`

Please help if any body has faced this issue

I am executing below runnable and at that time i am getting different holder values

```
private class SeekBarUpdaterRight implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (null != rightMusicPlayerHolder) {
                if (player != null) {
                    int curVolume = player.getCurrentPosition();
                   rightMusicPlayerHolder.seekMusicRight.setProgress(curVolume);
                    // int currentHour = curVolume / HOUR;
                    int currentMint = (curVolume % HOUR) / MINUTE;
                    int currentSec = (curVolume % MINUTE) / SECOND;
                    rightMusicPlayerHolder.txtDurationStartRight.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", currentMint, currentSec));
                    rightMusicPlayerHolder.seekMusicRight.postDelayed(this, 100);
                    Log.print("==========rightMusicPlayerHolder=========" + rightMusicPlayerHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you trying to fill an empty row in recycler view when that row is clicked?

Comment: Without adapter code there is no much help.

Answer (score 0):

`OnBindViewHolder()` gets called whenever something causes a change in the view, such as scrolling, keyboard opening/closing, pressing home or recents button etc. 
Make a global variable of your ViewHolder class and set the value in your `onClick()`. e.g.:

```
ViewHolder clickedViewHolder;

private void setClickedViewHolder(ViewHolder clickedViewHolder) {
    this.clickedViewHolder = clickedViewHolder;
}

private ViewHolder getClickedViewHolder() {
    return clickedViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.rowView.setTag(holder);
    holder.rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setCurrentViewHolder((MyAdapter.ViewHolder) v.getTag());
        }
    });

    ViewHolder currClickedViewHolder = getClickedViewHolder();  // this is the last viewHolder clicked on.
}
```

And do whatever you want with that ViewHolder.

Comment: Thanks for the help but issue is still there while executing runnable i am getting different holder every time so i am not able to set values in perticular seekbar

Comment: Can you describe your use case in more detail? What is it that you want to acheive?

Comment: Try setting `rightMusicPlayerHolder = getClickedViewHolder();` using above code.

Comment: This code will inevitably fail during scroll when `clickedViewHolder` gets reused in another position. You should ONLY hold clicked items position and check it during `onBindViewHolder` to apply progress.

Comment: It won't. The question asks for the last viewHolder that was clicked on and that's what the above code provides. Unless you click on the row item, `clickedViewHolder` will remain the previously clicked viewHolder or null when no row is yet clicked on.

Comment: I agree on holding only the position of the clicked item. But when the answer was written, @OP didn't mention what he planned to do with the viewHolder, so I just provided what he wanted.

Comment: Once user scrolls this `ViewHolder` out of viewport it will be recycled and bound to another item. So while it won't be null, it will no longer represent desired item.